# Is there any function in ace which returns me matching bracket position?

Tags: ace-editor

I have tried jumpToMatching() function, it takes me to the position of the matching bracket, but I need a function which returns me the position of the matching bracket. Is there any method which can help me?

Comment: do you mind editing `editor.js` to add a new function?

Comment: @MaherFattouh Sure, did you mean the ace library file?

Comment: Yes, I added the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: if it worked, mark it and vote it up, it lets others know and gives me sweet rep points :)

Comment: updated the answer, the file in called ace.js on the distribution. also added a more clear way to where you should add the function. just tested it, works perfectly.

Comment: Sure bro will check it out and mark it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking through the [default_commands.js](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/commands/default_commands.js#L400) there is no such function.

there's `jumptomatching`, `selecttomatching` and `expandToMatching`.

all three of them use the function `editor.jumpToMatching()` with different arguments.

digging through the code I found that function in [editor.js / ace.js](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/d1a77e9d2c54259f489a96b9f9789d4caa1e52d9/lib/ace/editor.js#L2028)

with some tweaking I was able to create the following working function:

```
this.returnMatchingPos = function() {
        var cursor = this.getCursorPosition();
        var iterator = new TokenIterator(this.session, cursor.row, cursor.column);
        var prevToken = iterator.getCurrentToken();
        var token = prevToken || iterator.stepForward();

        if (!token) return;

        //get next closing tag or bracket
        var matchType;
        var found = false;
        var depth = {};
        var i = cursor.column - token.start;
        var bracketType;
        var brackets = {
            ")": "(",
            "(": "(",
            "]": "[",
            "[": "[",
            "{": "{",
            "}": "{"
        };
        
        do {
            if (token.value.match(/[{}()\[\]]/g)) {
                for (; i < token.value.length && !found; i++) {
                    if (!brackets[token.value[i]]) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    bracketType = brackets[token.value[i]] + '.' + token.type.replace("rparen", "lparen");

                    if (isNaN(depth[bracketType])) {
                        depth[bracketType] = 0;
                    }

                    switch (token.value[i]) {
                        case '(':
                        case '[':
                        case '{':
                            depth[bracketType]++;
                            break;
                        case ')':
                        case ']':
                        case '}':
                            depth[bracketType]--;

                            if (depth[bracketType] === -1) {
                                matchType = 'bracket';
                                found = true;
                            }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (token && token.type.indexOf('tag-name') !== -1) {
                if (isNaN(depth[token.value])) {
                    depth[token.value] = 0;
                }
                
                if (prevToken.value === '<') {
                    depth[token.value]++;
                }
                else if (prevToken.value === '</') {
                    depth[token.value]--;
                }
                
                if (depth[token.value] === -1) {
                    matchType = 'tag';
                    found = true;
                }
            }

            if (!found) {
                prevToken = token;
                token = iterator.stepForward();
                i = 0;
            }
        } while (token && !found);

        //no match found
        if (!matchType)
            return;

        var range, pos;
        if (matchType === 'bracket') {
            range = this.session.getBracketRange(cursor);
            if (!range) {
                range = new Range(
                    iterator.getCurrentTokenRow(),
                    iterator.getCurrentTokenColumn() + i - 1,
                    iterator.getCurrentTokenRow(),
                    iterator.getCurrentTokenColumn() + i - 1
                );
                pos = range.start;
            }
        }
        else if (matchType === 'tag') {
            if (token && token.type.indexOf('tag-name') !== -1) 
                var tag = token.value;
            else
                return;

            range = new Range(
                iterator.getCurrentTokenRow(),
                iterator.getCurrentTokenColumn() - 2,
                iterator.getCurrentTokenRow(),
                iterator.getCurrentTokenColumn() - 2
            );

            //find matching tag
            if (range.compare(cursor.row, cursor.column) === 0) {
                found = false;
                do {
                    token = prevToken;
                    prevToken = iterator.stepBackward();
                    
                    if (prevToken) {
                        if (prevToken.type.indexOf('tag-close') !== -1) {
                            range.setEnd(iterator.getCurrentTokenRow(), iterator.getCurrentTokenColumn() + 1);
                        }

                        if (token.value === tag && token.type.indexOf('tag-name') !== -1) {
                            if (prevToken.value === '<') {
                                depth[tag]++;
                            }
                            else if (prevToken.value === '</') {
                                depth[tag]--;
                            }
                            
                            if (depth[tag] === 0)
                                found = true;
                        }
                    }
                } while (prevToken && !found);
            }

            //we found it
            if (token && token.type.indexOf('tag-name')) {
                pos = range.start;
                if (pos.row == cursor.row && Math.abs(pos.column - cursor.column) < 2)
                    pos = range.end;
            }
        }

        pos = range && range.cursor || pos;
        if (pos) {
            return pos;
        }
    };
```

open/edit `ace.js` and find this line: `this.jumpToMatching = function(select, expand) {`now paste the function I provided above just before the line you just found. save changes and close.

after that you can call it using `editor.returnMatchingPos()` and it should return an object with `row` and `column` just like `editor.getCursorPosition()`

#### Why not include it in my own code?

the existing functions use `TokenIterator` which is defined inside the file. using the function outside of editor object is possible if you can find a way to `var TokenIterator = require("./token_iterator").TokenIterator;` in your own code, and then change all instances of `this` into `editor` in the function I provided.